# WPF Label Design

Tags: wpf

I have a label in WPF which I want to restyle so it has rounded corners.

I have the below code already:

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type Label}">        
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
   </Style>
```

Can anyone please assist with how I would add a corner Radius to this label

many thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need to change the ControlTemplate for the Label in order to get rounded corners.  The Label control itself doesn't expose a CornerRadius property.

Add the following to your Style and you'll get rounded edges on your Label.  I arbitrarily set it to "3" below, but you can set it to whatever your needs dictate.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true" 
                CornerRadius="3">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the `Border` element would be simpler.

```
<Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue" Background="Red" Margin="2">
    <Label Content="Lorem ipsum" />
</Border>
```