# Display a horizontal table vertically in a Datagrid-WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a table displayed from a database.
I would like to display the horizontal Header Column-> Vertically

My table Structure is

```
  Server|Role|Status|Date
```

but I would like to display as

```
  Server
  Role
  Status
  Date
```

I tried the to flip the dataset, and tried to build it. Initially the build was successful but I can't view any data on my datagrid. 
kindly help , is there any other way to approach this problem ?

here is my code snippet

```
SqlConnection con;
SqlDataAdapter da = null;
DataSet ds = null;

private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [ServerDB_Test].[dbo].[ServerStatus] ", con);
       ds = new DataSet();
       foreach (DataTable dt in my_DataSet.Tables)
       {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));  }
                DataRow r;
                for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
                { 
                    r = table.NewRow();
                    r[0] = dt.Columns[k].ToString();
                    for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {  
                        r[j] = dt.Rows[j - 1][k]; 
                    }
                    table.Rows.Add(r);
                }
            ds.Tables.Add(table);
        }
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[1].DefaultView;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If I am not wrong, you must be seeing an empty dataGrid, right? because I see there is no data fetched and `da.fill` method is not called.. If you correct that, one more problem I see there is, after doing all transposing logics, you are feeding again the original datatable to `dataGrid1` change it it `ds.Tables[1]` instead of `ds.Tables[0]`

Comment: Yes, u r right. I see an empty datagrid.
but when I try to add da.Fill(ds);
there is err during buidling. 
let me try the option which you have given in the last sentence and will let u know

Comment: what error are you getting exactly? and if you don't do the `Fill`, there is no way you will get some output...

Comment: I edited the above code and added 
da.Fill(ds); and I changed the index to 1. Now when I debug, I see column headers but with blank datagrid :-(

Comment: may be there is no data for your query...

Comment: next to your `fill` method, keep break > F5 .. when broken, select `dt` > Shift+F9 > click on `find` type of icon.. can you see any data there? also please don't keep changing your code here in your question, it confuses..

Comment: post your answer if it worked for you..

Comment: I see an message- The name 'Fill' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Atlast I have found a way to display the table vertically, by working only on XAML..[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133429/wpf-label-design) was very useful. thanks all of you for ur replies.. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At first I tried rotating my Table in my DB using Pivot table, but couldn't succeed..

then I found to set the datagrid.layouttransform and a datagrid.Cellstyle for rotating the view of the table.

```
         <DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
             <TransformGroup>
                 <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                  <MatrixTransform Matrix="-1,0,0,1,0,0"/>
              </TransformGroup>
           </DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
           <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style  TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

and set the height and width of the columns accordingly and it works fine. 
Thanks !

Comment: great it helped you!

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to rotate the column, but not to keep the text vertical. You helped immensely.